# Python, Lama (locally). CreatingTelegram bot using llama_cpp. Bot don't respond on any commands and requests

Tags: python, aiogram, llama-cpp-python

Python, Lama (locally). I am creatingTelegram bot using llama_cpp. Bot don't respond on any commands and requests. The pycharm code itself does not produce errors, but the bot does not respond to commands and messages. HELP PLEASE.
The aiogram library version 3.0.1 is used.

```
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import logging
import asyncio
from aiogram.dispatcher.router import Router
from llama_cpp import Llama

# Инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token="MY-TG-Token")  # Замените "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN" на реальный токен вашего бота

# Инициализируем Llama
llama = Llama(model_path="./llama-2-7b-chat.gguf.q8_0.bin")

dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
router = Router()

# Функция для вызова Llama и обработки сообщения
async def process_message(message_text):
    result = await asyncio.to_thread(llama.process_message, message_text)
    return result

# Обработка команды /start
router.message(commands=['start'])
async def on_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет! Этот бот обрабатывает сообщения с помощью Llama локально.")

# Обработка всех остальных сообщений
router.message(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def on_message(message: types.Message):
    # Отправляем сообщение "..." как индикатор обработки
    processing_msg = await message.answer("...")

    # Вызываем Llama для обработки сообщения
    result = await process_message(message.text)

    # Обновляем текст сообщения на результат обработки
    await bot.edit_message_text(text=result, chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=processing_msg.message_id)

# Обработчик для личных сообщений с текстовым контентом
router.message(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT, is_private=True)
async def handle_private_message(message: types.Message):
    # Ваш код обработки личных сообщений здесь
    await message.answer("Вы отправили мне личное сообщение: " + message.text)

async def main():
    # Запускаем long-polling
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```